# Get dataURI signature, send by js, from previous php to current php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, signature

I am out of hope for this question to which the answer will finally complete my project.

I am using a signature plugin/API ( https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad ) as one of the input fields in a form in the first file form.php.
When the form is submitted I am sending the data to a database and retrieve useful data. this useful data is seen in the second file success.php.
I have successfully gotten the all data except the signature.

[image: flowchart of how this works]

The signature is not an `<input>` but a `<canvas>` because of the plugins
when the form is submitted a javascript file sends the signature toDataURL a function from the documentation of signaturepad.js. Currently I have send it to a window.open new window. The url shows a data64 text which when converted is a image.

The problem is accessing this dataURL from success.php. When I can to this I can also send it to a database and send it within the automatic mail.

how do I get my signature to the second file as an image?

this is my code:

form.php

```
<form id="form">
<canvas id="signature"></canvas>
```

form.js

```
var signature = $("#signature");
var signaturePad = new SignaturePad(signature);
$("#form").submit(function(e) {
signaturePad.toDataURL(); )};
```

success.php (my idea how it should work)

```
<?php $image = $_POST['signaturePad']; ?>
<?php echo "<img src='"$image"'>";
```

success.php within SQL statements

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO $table ($field) VALUES ($image)";
```

I have also tried other options and API/plugins but I think this would be the best solution.

Comment: Can you use cookies/sessions?

Comment: can you do a var_dump on the post parameter?

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: success.php says: Notice: Undefined index: signaturePad.
this was an indication how it should work

it doesn't pass along the signature var / dataURI while posting the form. I can open the created signature(dataURI) in another browser with window.open but I cannot retrieve this information in my success.php

thanks for help already :)

Comment: Are you sure you're actually sending any data to the server? You don't return anything from the submit handler function or set value of any hidden input. I can't remember exactly how to send additional data using `.submit()`, but you could add a hidden input to your form and inside the submit handler set its value like this:
`$('myHiddenInput').val(signaturePad.toDataURL()); return true;`